# How can I make this recursive method to an iterative method?

Tags: java

I need to make the `Raju()` method using for loop how so i do it?

```
public class Fall2012COP3337MidtermRecursion 
{
    // trace recursion
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {        
        System.out.println("Raju(6) = " + Raju(6));        
    }

    // compute the nth Raju number
    private static long Raju(int n)
    {        
        if (n < 0)
           return 0L;
        if (n == 0 || n == 1)
           return 1L;

        return Raju(n-1) + Raju(n-2) + 1; // recurse
    }
}
```

Comment: As this is obviously homework, what steps have you taken to figure it out yourself? Recursion<->Iteration is one of those things you don't just want someone to figure out for you - you *want* to know the difference and how to convert between the two

Comment: I understand recursion i know how it works but its so hard to make it iterative. at least for me

Comment: This looks more like a midterm question than homework.

Comment: it is my midterm practice test i have my midterm next thursday for programing 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static long Raju_Iterative(int n)
{        
    if (n < 0)
        return 0L;
    long a = 1L;
    long b = 1L;
    for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
        long c = a+b+1;
        a = b;
        b = c;
    }
    return b;
}
```

Comment: @LexyFeito You could set `i` to 0 and loop as long as `i<n-1`. You are right it's more common to start at 0, I edit the answer. Essential is that you loop n-1 times. I set it to 2 because this was the first value of n I wanted the loop to execute.

Comment: so what is the reason to loop n-1 times, is there a formula to do this?

Comment: holy crap man i just came up with this way to do and it works

Answer (score 2):

this should do it... and it compiles. corrected version of the post below from Lewyx. (loop condition and compile errors)

```
public class Fall2012COP3337MidtermRecursion {
    // trace recursion
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20 ; i++){
            System.out.println("RajuRecursion("+i+") = " + RajuRecursion(i)); 
            System.out.println("RajuIterative("+i+") = " + RajuIterative(i));

            // we see same results :)
        }
    }

    // decent iterative variant
    private static long RajuIterative(int n){

        long sum=0;
        long l1 = 1;
        long l2 = 1;

        if(n<0) return 0L; 
        if(n<2) return 1L;

        while(0<--n)
        {
            sum=l1+l2+1;
            l2=l1;
            l1=sum;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    // compute the nth Raju number
    private static long RajuRecursion(int n)
    {        
        if (n < 0)
           return 0L;
        if (n == 0 || n == 1)
           return 1L;

        return RajuRecursion(n-1) + RajuRecursion(n-2) + 1; // recurse
    }
}
```

Result is:

```
RajuRecursion(0) = 1
RajuIterative(0) = 1
RajuRecursion(1) = 1
RajuIterative(1) = 1
RajuRecursion(2) = 3
RajuIterative(2) = 3
RajuRecursion(3) = 5
RajuIterative(3) = 5
RajuRecursion(4) = 9
RajuIterative(4) = 9
RajuRecursion(5) = 15
RajuIterative(5) = 15
RajuRecursion(6) = 25
RajuIterative(6) = 25
RajuRecursion(7) = 41
RajuIterative(7) = 41
RajuRecursion(8) = 67
RajuIterative(8) = 67
....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static long Raju(int n) {
    if (n < 0) return 0;
    if (n < 2) return 1;

    long nm1 = 1, nm2 = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
        long raju = nm1 + nm2 + 1;
        nm2 = nm1;
        nm1 = raju;
    }

    return raju;
}
```